# Symfony forms entity/document sorting the property

Tags: sorting, symfony, doctrine, formbuilder

I'm using the symfony forms for creating a select-box with all my users.
I display them by fullname, but want to sort them alphabetically.

```
$builder->add('transferTo', 'document', [
        'class' => 'UserBundle:User',
        'property' => 'fullname',
        'label'  => 'Overdragen aan',
        'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control selectpicker'],
        'label_attr' => ['class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label'],
        'multiple'  => false,
        'required' => true
    ]);
```

How can i sort the users alphabetically on fullname of firstName?

Comment: Can show a snapshot of the output and the one you want?

Comment: It outputs a regular select with a few options (fullnames).
But i want those names sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 22):

What you need is to add queryBuilder to the form params

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

$builder->add('transferTo', 'document', [
    'class' => 'UserBundle:User',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $repository) { 
            return $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')->orderBy('u.fullname', 'ASC');
        }
    'property' => 'fullname',
    'label'  => 'Overdragen aan',
    'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control selectpicker'],
    'label_attr' => ['class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label'],
    'multiple'  => false,
    'required' => true
]);
```

I assumed the fieldname in your entity is `u.fullname`

Comment: No errors but my select box isn't ordered either. (ASC nor DESC works)

Comment: Using ODM (MongoDB)

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentRepository;

'query_builder' => function(DocumentRepository $repository) {

                return $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')->sort('u.firstName', 'desc');

            },


But still not sorting

Comment: Are you using MongoDB?

Comment: Yes i'm using MongoDB.
I used sort instead of orderBy, used "document" instead of "entity" and Use DocumentRepository instead of EntityRepository.

My select box isn't sorted but there aren't errors either.

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge about MongoDB but I suggest to check this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968415/symfony2-dynamic-forms-mongodb]

Comment: Thanks for helping! I hope someone finds out how to sort the results, all example's on the net are the same as yours (and mine)... All names are shown but not sorted.

Comment: I know the solution is adding the queryBuilder to form builder params either it's Doctrine or MongoDB; If you could find it it will help you